# How to Use Variable Elimination Using Joint Probablities as Factros

Tags: probability

Given the graph $A$->$B$->$C$, $A$ is independent of $C$ given $B$. I have the joint probability distribution of $A$ and $B$ as $P(A,B)$ and the joint probability distribution of $B$ and $C$ as $P(B, C)$. How to compute the probability distribution of $B$  as $P(B)= \sum_{AC} P(A,B,C)$ using Variable elimination procedure ? All the examples I find is using the conditional probabilities as factors. But all I have is the joints $P(A,B)$ and $P(B, C)$ and  **I dont want to do the extra step of computing the conditional tables first and then follow the examples**. I read that the factors can be joint probabilities not conditional probabilities according to this link [Variable Elimination](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ea23gao/cs486686_f21/lecture_notes/Lecture_13_on_Variable_Elimination_Algorithm.pdf)